# How to split datetime into date and time in informatica

Tags: business-intelligence

I am using Informatica 8.1.1. Source flat file contains one date/time field. I want to load it as two separate columns date and time in target table. 
I tried TO_DATE function to get the date and time separately.
But it is giving some errors.

How can I split this date/time into date and time?
or 
Can we load a string value from source flat file  into a date value in target table?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following to load the flat file:

For the date field:

```
to_char(get_date_part(in_date,'YYYY'))||to_cha r(get_date_part(in_date,'MM'))||to_char(get_date_pa rt(in_date,'DD'))
```

For the time field:

```
to_char(get_date_part(in_date,'HH24'))||to_cha r(get_date_part(in_date,'MI'))||to_char(get_date_pa rt(in_date,'SS'))
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to split. just connect date and time column with the same port.

Answer (score -2):

Read the help section on the GETDATEPART function